OnClick event is not trigger when using Two steps Page Directive in blazor server
I am working on a project(Blazor Server) where I have few components in Admin folder, If I set page directive like "/Admin/CreateCategory" the Onclick stops working on the page. Render Mode is set to Interactive Server on page.
When I change the page directive to "/Admin-CreateCategory" Onclick start working.
I want to keep this style "/Admin/CreateCategory" please tell me why my Onclick stops working on this style of page directives?

Here is my test code and I can't reproduce the issue, so could you kindly provide more details.

[Polite] No idea.  Without your code that demonstrates the problem this question can't be  answered.

Blazor doesn't support hierarchical routing. You can only have one level and the subsequent entries are considered route parameters.
In your case you must work with /Admin-CreateCategory

It work with hierarchical routing the problem was . . . . I was not uasing  tage in app.razor after that its is working.
